# command which repeats one line of its normal output

Tags: bash, command, output

on ( debian 11 / Xfce ) to show lightdm.conf at first I used this command

```
~$ /usr/sbin/lightdm --show-config 
   [Seat:*]
-----------
Sources:
B  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/01_debian.conf
B  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/01_debian.conf   ---> same as above
C  /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/lightdm.conf
D  /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

then I tried

```
~$ sudo lightdm --show-config 
   [Seat:*]
----------
Sources:
A  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/01_debian.conf
B  /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/lightdm.conf
C  /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

which gives normal output. But even more puzzling, for me, is that if I use sudo with the first command, which I normally should not do, I get the right output :

```
~$ sudo /usr/sbin/lightdm --show-config 
   [Seat:*]
---------
Sources:
A  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/01_debian.conf
B  /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/lightdm.conf
C  /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

I tried nothing because I am completely puzzled by this problem. I have no idea whatsoever where to start looking or what to look for.

Comment: Interesting question but wrong forum, try https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or https://superuser.com/ or something similar.

Comment: sorry for that .

Comment: In the first instance, you have "/usr/share" referenced twice in you ${PATH}.  "sudo" in both cases runs as if superuser was executing, and its ${PATH} does not have that duplicate reference.

Comment: @Eric Marceau the problem lies in a double reference to /usr/share in the value of XDG_DATA_DIRS which itself comes from /usr/bin/x-session-manager and /usr/bin/startxfce4 as explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/564003/xdg-data-dirs-contains-duplicate-paths-how-to-fix).